# Replace text in a specific character number

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column (text) with values like '601.001.010'. 11 characters.

I want to replace characters 9,10,11 as follows. 010 to 001, 020 to 002, 030 to 003 and so on.

I have tried this SQL statement:

```sql
update "table" 
set code = replace (right(code, 3) '010', '001')
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What does "and so on" mean? Is it only `010` to `090` you're interested in? What about `100, 200` etc? What are the *rules*?

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens CHAR(11));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES 
('601.001.010'),
('601.001.020 '),
('601.001.070');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
    , result = STUFF(tokens, 9, 3, LEFT('0' + RIGHT(tokens, 3), 3))
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 601.001.010 | 601.001.001 |
| 2 | 601.001.020 | 601.001.002 |
| 3 | 601.001.070 | 601.001.007 |